# XNA XML Serialization Issue

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xna, deserialization

I am using the code below to serialize/deserialize game data to a .lst file:

```
    public static void SaveData(StoreData data)
    {
        // Get the path of the save game
        string fullpath = Path.Combine("Content", filename);

        // Open the file, creating it if necessary
        FileStream stream = File.Open(fullpath, FileMode.Create);

        try
        {
            // Convert the object to XML data and put it in the stream
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StoreData));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the file
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

The serialization seems to work fine most of the time. Here is the file created:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StoreData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <score>2540</score>
  <level>8</level>
  <difficulty>true</difficulty>
  <sound>true</sound>
  <mouseControl>true</mouseControl>
</StoreData>
```

But on occasion the serialization seems to go wrong and upon opening the file it seems an extra couple of characters is added to the end of the file to create something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StoreData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <score>2540</score>
  <level>8</level>
  <difficulty>true</difficulty>
  <sound>true</sound>
  <mouseControl>true</mouseControl>
</StoreData>a>  ---> extra bit added
```

This causes the game to crash when trying to deserialize because it's not in the correct format. If anyone knows why this happens or what i'm doing wrong please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm; normally when this gets reported, they aren't using FileMode.Create. However you are using this correctly. Odd. Are the extra bits the end of XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your using File.Open

Instead use new FileStream

FileStream stream = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Create);

The File.Open is canceling out FileMode.Create

Comment: Oh I see. I just tried it out and it seems to have fixed the issue, thanks for your help Daniel.